# Angular decrement value in array

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, decrement

I try to decrement a value in my array, but I can't get it to work.
My array `data` contains attributes and everytime a method gets clicked, I call that value from a service and increment it in the array object. The getter is equal to `amountCounter`.

My main problem is that whenever I try to remove an array object, my `amountCounter` won't also decrement the value which it had before, but the array object gets removed.

I also put two pictures to better clarify my problem, thank you so much for every help.

app.component.html

```
<h2>Add values of my service into array:</h2>
<p>Array:</p>
<p>Total: {{amountCounter}}</p>

<div *ngFor="let item of data, let i = index;">
  <span>ID: {{item.id}}</span>
  <span>Title: {{item.title}}</span>
  <span (click)="removeElement(i, item.amountCounter)" class="material-icons">
    close
    </span>
</div>
```

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {
  clickEventsubscription: Subscription

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  id: number;
  title: String;
  amountCounter: number;
  data: any = [];

  constructor(private share: ShareDataService) {
    this.clickEventsubscription = this.share.getClickEvent().subscribe(() => {
      this.initialize();
    })
  }

  removeElement(id: number, counter: number) {
    this.data.splice(id, 1);
    this.amountCounter -= counter //In that line I can't get it to work that my attribute decrements
    console.log("before" + this.amountCounter);
    console.log("after:" + counter);
  }

  initialize() {
    this.id = this.share.getId();
    this.title = this.share.getTitle();
    this.amountCounter = this.share.getAmountCounter();

    const newData = {
      id: this.id,
      title: this.title,
      amountCounter: this.amountCounter
    };

    this.data.push(newData);
    console.log(this.data);
  }
}
```

share-data.service.ts

```
export class ShareDataService {
  private subject = new Subject<any>();

  title: String;
  id: number;
  amountCounter: number;

  getId() {
    return this.id;
  }

  getTitle() {
    return this.title;
  }

  getAmountCounter(){
    return this.amountCounter;
  }

  sendClickEvent() {
    this.subject.next();
  }

  getClickEvent(): Observable<any> {
    return this.subject.asObservable();
  }

}
```

[That is how my array looks before ID 1 is clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CGsx.png)

[That is how my array looks after I clicked at "X", but it decrements wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGcsF.png)

Thank you so much!

Comment: `removeElement(id: number` might become `removeElement(index: number` just to avoid confusion. The rest is pretty messy I'm not sure for what you need the `subject`

Comment: Thank you for the tip, but can you atleast tell me what is messy so I can try to explain what I am doing here. The subject is needed so I can call a function from another component, which is also used from my app.component.ts component.

Comment: Please create a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/)

Comment: Thanks for offering me your help, I will do it as fast as I can.

Comment: be sure is a "number" (or convert on fly). In .html `(click)="removeElement(i, +item.amountCounter)"` -see the "+" sign to convert to a number. BTW, Angular transpile to javaScript, and in javaScript a variable can be number or string. When we sy that a variable is number, nobody sure that we are going to received a number -only help us to avoid errors-

Comment: I have made a StackBlitz and would really appreciate it if you can help me with my problem: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-shdyrw?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the behavior you are after but generally this method will calculate the sum of the array values

```
  getTotalAmount(): number {
    return this.data.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.amount, 0);
  }
```

The main issue I found very difficult to figure out is that you have `amountCounter` in [share-data.service, dialog.component, app.component]

I suppose you want to add new items using `dialog.component` with different `amount` values.

Here you add new item to your 'data' array, the values for single item comes from `share` service which was updated in your `dialog.component`

```
  initialize() {
    console.log("initialize");
    const id = this.share.getId();
    const title = this.share.getTitle();
    const amount = this.share.getAmount();

    const newData = {
      id,
      title,
      amount
    };

    this.data.push(newData);
  }
```

To summarize the flow:

- in `dialog.component` you update field values in share-data.service `clickMe()` method
- that method will trigger a method in `app.component` called `initialize` which will add the new item to the `this.data` array.
- if you click on item (to remove it) `splice` will do it, and Angular will refresh the `Total` calling the `getTotalAmount` method

Working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dp4dus?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and effort, you really helped me to solve that issue which I couldn't solve for weeks. I was so close to giving up because no one could help me with that and you Sir robert, thanks a lot I can't just thank enough. You are really awesome and I wish you much success and luck for your future, I hope that you will help other people too with your knowledge, god bless you.

Comment: Is it possible to use that ```return this.data.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.amount, 0);``` line also if I have more then one amount? For example if I don't only have 29.99 as a number but also 8, 16, 25... does it also count all of them and reduce it? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: yes, it will pick the correct amount. In your `modal.component` you can specify different amounts from user input. To better understand how `reduce` works check this [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)